# Trim off trailing letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I need to trim off whichever letters are at the end of a reference number.

Example: If the reference number is `ABC/12345A` or `ABC/12345ABBBBC` or `ABC/12345WRBV` , it should be left with only `ABC/12345`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you checked the solution ?

Comment: Is it always xxx/nnnnn result expected? I.e. 3 characters, a slash and 5 digits?

Comment: yes, it will always as above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Substring()`, `CHARINDEX()` and `Patindex()` as below :

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(32)

SET @DATA = 'ABC/12345WRBV'

SELECT REPLACE(@DATA, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('/', @DATA), LEN(@DATA)), PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('/', @DATA), LEN(@DATA))), LEN(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('/', @DATA), LEN(@DATA)))), '') AS DATA
```

**Result :**

```
+================+
| DATA           |
+================+
| ABC/12345      |
+----------------+
```